# Adding background in flutter dashboard

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Please any expert who can suggest to me how to a background picture in this dashboard, I'll be very thankful.
When I add boxfit in the following scaffold widget the code got red lines.

Please any expert who can suggest to me how to a background picture in this dashboard, I'll be very thankful.
When I add boxfit in the following scaffold widget the code got red lines.

```
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:maps_app/screens/Dash_board.dart';

class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/home1';
  @override
  DashboardState createState() => new DashboardState();
}

class DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffffffff),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 110,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "ColorLine",
                      style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black87,
                              fontSize: 24,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 4,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      " Home",
                      style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff000000),
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 70,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  icon: Image.asset(
                    "assets/colorline.png",
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          GridDashboard()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/background.jpeg"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    child: ...
  ),
);
```

---

[image]

Comment: When I add the above code for the dashboard background, the child code just become red lines.

Comment: @waseemafzal I check this solution in my computer. And attach screenshot. Can you attach screen your emulator, and full widget code.

Comment: Please check out the error image on the following link, https://ibb.co/z67QCmb

Comment: @waseemafzal You try set in child param list of widgets, but Container widget in param child can take only one widget. Container(child: Column(children:[ ... list of tour widgets]))

Comment: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/background.jpeg"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    child: Column(children:[ SizeBox(),Container()])
  ),

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is wrap your Scaffold with a Container Widget. Also, you need to make the Scaffold's color transparent. I will be using a bit of Vlad Konoshenko's answer to help you with this.

```dart
return Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/background.jpeg"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      // Rest of the code remains same.
      ...
    ),
);
```